# rails simple form not getting created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I have created a very simple example form me but some how my for is not getting submitted below are components:

```
This is my controller:

    class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    logger.info "from new"
    @profile = Profile.new
    logger.info "after new"
  end

  def show

  end

   def list
      @profile = Profile.find(:all)
   end

  def create
    logger.info "from create"
    @profile = Profile.new(user_basic_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to '/show'
    else
      render 'show'
      logger.info "Save failed"
      flash[:notice] = "Didn't work"
    end

  end

  def index
  end

   def user_basic_params
    logger.info "from user_basic_params"
    params.require(:profile).permit(:email, :password, :file, :active, :sex, choises: [])
   end


end
```

This is my view:

```
 <div class="container center-block">
        <div class="row">



    <form class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
    <h3> Create new profile </h3>  
    </div>  

   <%= simple_form_for (@profile)  do |f| %>

   <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :milk_animal, as: :radio_buttons, collection:            ['Cow','Any'], placeholder: 'Enter Milk Animal' %>
   </div>



  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :milk_type, as: 
  :radio_buttons, collection: ['Toned','Any'], placeholder: 'Milk Type' %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :brand, placeholder: 'Brand' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Time_of_Delivery %>  
  <%= f.time_select :time_of_delivery, placeholder: 'Time of Delivery' %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Start_Date %>  
  <%= f.date_select :start_date, placeholder: 'Start Date' %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :delivery_days, as: :check_boxes,
    collection: [
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Satusday',
      'All'],
      wrapper: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes %>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>

   </div>

    <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :address, as: :text, placeholder: 'Address' %>

   </div>

    <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :pincode, placeholder: 'Pincode' %>

   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.input :contact_no, placeholder: 'Contact No' %>

   </div>

   <%= f.button :submit %>
   <% end %>


   </form>
   </div>

</div>
```

my model name is profile and controller name is profiles
in my route.rb file its written:resources :profiles

when I look for the html source generated in the browser the form is rendered in this way :

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_profile" id="new_profile" action="/profiles/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+qcqmHIbaskK/QIu5vy66UY9xHlzr8TkpwAUFzkM+Q5SwaU6Zy6qQLhfZYgsGuLS+XU8ghX+C+aHJPrO2u6BWg==" />
```

its seems by looking at action that is will go to create method, but it does not.

and finally my console output is :

```
Started GET "/profiles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-31 00:49:48 +0530
Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
from new
after new
Rendered profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (142.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 178ms (Views: 166.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

Started GET "/profiles/new?utf8=%E2%9C  
Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
Parameters:  "brand"=>"Amul",       "commit"=>"Create Profile"}
from new
after new
Rendered profiles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (158.2ms)

I have deleted few parameter in output
```

Comment: Can you provide the form template code?

Comment: I have edited the question and view is visible now.

Comment: I think the problem is because of extra form so please remove extra form tag i.e. `<form class="form-horizontal"></form>`

Comment: thanks Amit, now I can move on

Comment: you can add class to simple form also e.g. `<%= simple_form_for @user, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } }`